# How to get the content of textarea

Tags: python, html, textarea

I have this `textarea` form:

```
self.response.out.write("""        

<form name="title" 
action="/edittitlepitchhandler" 
method="post">            

...

pitch: <br />
<textarea name="new_pitch" rows="13" cols="75">
"%s"
</textarea><br /><br />

...                    

<input type="submit" 
value="submit">
</form>""" % (..., m.pitch, ...) )
```

I am trying to get the content of the `textarea` with `"%s"` but I think the `"%s"` inside `<textarea></textarea>` is picked up as initial text and the textarea box contains quotes. How do I get the content of the `textarea` so that I can open it later and edit it?

Thanks.

**Edit**

As per Chris Morgan's comment I deleted the quotes and removed the spaces before `%s` like this

```
pitch: <br />
<textarea name="new_pitch" rows="13" cols="75">%s</textarea><br /><br />
```

Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Why `"%s"` rather than just `%s`?

Comment: @chris - why not make that an answer and have the OP mark as accepted?

Comment: @Kev: I wasn't at sure if that was what he meant because I just couldn't understand quite what he didn't understand.  Plus I was overdue to go to bed so I didn't want to make it more than a single line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `textarea` displays all the text inside it, so if you put `<textarea>"%s"</textarea>`, it'll put the quotes in as well. Scrap the quotes and it'll just show the expanded `%s`.